# How to change project structure in AdonisJs?

Tags: node.js, package.json, adonis.js

[image: Approximate structure of the project]

`client` - Vue.js project
`server` - AdonisJs API

Vue.js works fine but AdonisJs doesn't want to start.

[image: error]

How can this be implemented using only one `package.json`?

Comment: You need to remove everything.
Create a parent folder divided by front and server where you can create projects in that folder technology in which you want.

Answer (score 1):

In Adonis v5 you can do it by changing the `.adonisrc.json`.

> The .adonisrc.json file is stored inside the root of your project. It configures the workspace and some of the runtime settings of your AdonisJS application.
> The file only contains the minimum required configuration to run your application.

You can view the complete file contents by running the following ace command.

```
node ace dump:rcfile
```

You can dig deeper by reading their documents on
https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/adonisrc-file#directories.

> An object of known directories and their pre-configured paths. You can change the path to match your requirements.

Comment: Notice that it doesn't work, e.g., for Controllers. In this case we need change the "namespaces" rule: https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/controllers#controllers-location

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29883454)